# Build executable jar in docker container using Maven

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

How can I build an executable jar file in a docker container using Maven?

A simplified example of what I am trying to solve.

**Local repo layout:**

[image: local repo layout]

**Main:**

```
package org.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-troubleshooting</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**Local machine workflow(working as expected):**

```
mvn clean package
```

> ...[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

```
java -jar target/maven-troubleshooting-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

> Hello world!

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
COPY src /usr/src/app
```

**Docker workflow:**

> docker build . -t simplified-mvn-troubleshooting
> docker run -it simplified-mvn-troubleshooting bash

(now in the running container)

> mvn clean package
> ...[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

> java -jar target/maven-troubleshooting-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.Main
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean to `RUN mvn package` in the Dockerfile?  With what you've shown you're copying the source code but not building it at all.  (Don't forget to also declare the main container `CMD` to launch the Java process as well.)

Comment: How would you do it in maven outside docker?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I've shown this in the question description exactly.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm running mvn package manually after attaching to the container as shown in the steps in the question description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this after a few hours of trial and error. It appears Maven is pretty strict with directory structure. I changed my dockerfile to the below which solved the issue.

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11 AS build
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src /src
```

I can now package and run the jar all in the docker container directly after attaching to the container.

Comment: Next time, look inside the jar file to see what is there, and compare with the functional one.   `COPY . .` is your friend.